# add attribute to element xml

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I want add attribute to my balise xml.

```
    set serveroutput on;
    DECLARE
      doc  xmltype := xmltype(
      '<workbook>
         <worksheet sheetName="MySheet1" sheetId="1"/>
         <worksheet sheetName="MySheet2" sheetId="2"/>
         <worksheet sheetName="MySheet3" sheetId="3"/>
       </workbook>');
    BEGIN
    select updatexml(doc,'workbook','<workbook id="1"></workbook>') into                 doc from dual;            
    dbms_output.put_line(doc.getclobval());
    END;
```

but if i add  I no longer have 'worksheet' tags.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add an attribute to the existing node, rather than add an additional node, you can use `insertchildxml`:

```
insertchildxml(doc, '/workbook', '@id', '1')
```

So in your code:

```
DECLARE
  doc  xmltype := xmltype(
  '<workbook>
     <worksheet sheetName="MySheet1" sheetId="1"/>
     <worksheet sheetName="MySheet2" sheetId="2"/>
     <worksheet sheetName="MySheet3" sheetId="3"/>
   </workbook>');
  txt clob;
BEGIN
  select insertchildxml(doc, '/workbook', '@id', '1') into doc from dual;            
  dbms_output.put_line(doc.getclobval());
END;
/

<workbook id="1"><worksheet sheetName="MySheet1" sheetId="1"/><worksheet sheetName="MySheet2" sheetId="2"/><worksheet sheetName="MySheet3" sheetId="3"/></workbook>

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

or formatted for readability:

```
DECLARE
  doc  xmltype := xmltype(
  '<workbook>
     <worksheet sheetName="MySheet1" sheetId="1"/>
     <worksheet sheetName="MySheet2" sheetId="2"/>
     <worksheet sheetName="MySheet3" sheetId="3"/>
   </workbook>');
  txt clob;
BEGIN
  select insertchildxml(doc, '/workbook', '@id', '1') into doc from dual;            
  select xmlserialize(document doc indent size=2) into txt from dual;            
  dbms_output.put_line(txt);
END;
/

<workbook id="1">
  <worksheet sheetName="MySheet1" sheetId="1"/>
  <worksheet sheetName="MySheet2" sheetId="2"/>
  <worksheet sheetName="MySheet3" sheetId="3"/>
</workbook>


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

But [`insertchildxml` is deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/INSERTCHILDXML.html) (as is [`appendchildxml`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/APPENDCHILDXML.html)), so you can do this with an XMLQuery instead:

```
xmlquery('copy $out := $in modify
    ( insert node attribute id {"1"} into $out/workbook )
    return $out'
  passing doc as "in" returning content)
```

Again in your code and formatted for display:

```
DECLARE
  doc  xmltype := xmltype(
  '<workbook>
     <worksheet sheetName="MySheet1" sheetId="1"/>
     <worksheet sheetName="MySheet2" sheetId="2"/>
     <worksheet sheetName="MySheet3" sheetId="3"/>
   </workbook>');
  txt clob;
BEGIN
  select xmlquery('copy $out := $in modify
      ( insert node attribute id {"1"} into $out/workbook )
      return $out'
    passing doc as "in" returning content)
  into doc from dual;            
  select xmlserialize(document doc indent size=2) into txt from dual;            
  dbms_output.put_line(txt);
END;
/

<workbook id="1">
  <worksheet sheetName="MySheet1" sheetId="1"/>
  <worksheet sheetName="MySheet2" sheetId="2"/>
  <worksheet sheetName="MySheet3" sheetId="3"/>
</workbook>


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You can also pass the attribute value in to the XPath:

```
DECLARE
  doc  xmltype := xmltype(
  '<workbook>
     <worksheet sheetName="MySheet1" sheetId="1"/>
     <worksheet sheetName="MySheet2" sheetId="2"/>
     <worksheet sheetName="MySheet3" sheetId="3"/>
   </workbook>');
  txt clob;
BEGIN
  select xmlquery('copy $out := $in modify
      ( insert node attribute id {$id} into $out/workbook )
      return $out'
    passing doc as "in", 42 as "id" returning content)
  into doc from dual;            
  select xmlserialize(document doc indent size=2) into txt from dual;            
  dbms_output.put_line(txt);
END;
/

<workbook id="42">
  <worksheet sheetName="MySheet1" sheetId="1"/>
  <worksheet sheetName="MySheet2" sheetId="2"/>
  <worksheet sheetName="MySheet3" sheetId="3"/>
</workbook>


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

---

If you want to add a namespace as an attribute you could do:

```
DECLARE
  doc  xmltype := xmltype(
  '<workbook>
     <worksheet sheetName="MySheet1" sheetId="1"/>
     <worksheet sheetName="MySheet2" sheetId="2"/>
     <worksheet sheetName="MySheet3" sheetId="3"/>
   </workbook>');
  txt clob;
BEGIN
  select xmlquery('copy $out := $in modify
      ( insert node attribute {concat("xmlns:", $id)} {$path} into $out/workbook )
      return $out'
    passing doc as "in", 'ns' as "id", 'http://example.com' as "path" returning content)
  into doc from dual;            
  select xmlserialize(document doc indent size=2) into txt from dual;            
  dbms_output.put_line(txt);
END;
/

<workbook xmlns:ns="http://example.com" xmlns:xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/">
  <worksheet sheetName="MySheet1" sheetId="1"/>
  <worksheet sheetName="MySheet2" sheetId="2"/>
  <worksheet sheetName="MySheet3" sheetId="3"/>
</workbook>


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

but as your nodes don't have namespaces that seems a bit pointless.

Comment: Thank you guy !
But have an idea how can add attribute xmlns with xmlquery ?
         insert node attribute xmlns {"1"} into $out/workbook

Comment: because i have this error :
invalid namespace in attribute constructors

Comment: Your XML doesn't have any namespaces?

Comment: The XML in your question doesn't have any namespaces; and if you have nodes that are already prefixed then the namespace must already be declared, or it wouldn't be a valid XMLType object. I suggest you ask a new question explaining what you are actually trying to do with a more realistic example.